# Matplotlib stops animating after first frame

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate two subplots, each with multiple lines. I am using [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), and I am using the [`FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation), which is used by many of the [animation examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html).

#### Using animation:

If I try to animate it, I only get the result of the first frame:
[image: with animation]

#### Without using animation:

If I manually call my `update_lines` function, it works fine.
[image: without animation]

#### Code:

Below is the full code (uncommenting the 3 indicated lines in `main()` works, but I would like to see it update in real-time, hence trying to use the animation).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def make_subplots():
    def setup_axes(axes):
        for ax in axes:
            ax.set_xbound(0, 100)  # bound will change as needed.
            ax.set_ylim(0, 1)  # limit won't change automatically.

    def make_lines(axes):
        labels = ('a', 'b', 'c')
        lines = []
        for ax in axes:
            ax_lines = []
            for label in labels:
                x, y = [0], [0]
                line, = ax.plot(x, y, label=label)  # comma for unpacking.
                ax_lines.append((line, x, y))
            lines.append(ax_lines)
        return lines

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    lines = make_lines(axes)
    setup_axes(axes)
    return fig, axes, lines


def make_data():
    for i in xrange(100):
        print 'make_data():', i
        data = dict()
        for label in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
            from random import random
            data[label] = random()
        yield (i + 1, data)


def update_lines(data, lines):
    print 'update_lines():', data, lines
    updated_lines = []
    for ax_lines in lines:
        for line, x, y in ax_lines:
            label = line.get_label()
            x.append(data[0])
            y.append(data[1][label])
            line.set_data(x, y)
            updated_lines.append(line)


def main():
    fig, axes, lines = make_subplots()

    # Uncomment these 3 lines, and it works!
    # new_data = make_data()
    # for data in new_data:
    #     update_lines(data, lines)

    FuncAnimation(fig=fig,
                  func=update_lines,
                  frames=make_data,
                  fargs=(lines,),
                  interval=10,
                  blit=False)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I've never tried to use this class, but I suspect your problem is with func=make_data

Comment: @DavidMarx If it is, I'm not sure where or how. I've tried making the gnerator a list by changing the line to `frames=list(make_data()),` with no luck. The `frames` argument is supposed to accept any iterable, so I didn't think that would help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### (Undocumented?) Hooks

So, I was digging around the source-code of `matplotlib.animation.Animation`, and I noticed these lines in the `__init__()` function:

```
# Clear the initial frame
self._init_draw()

# Instead of starting the event source now, we connect to the figure's
# draw_event, so that we only start once the figure has been drawn.
self._first_draw_id = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self._start)
```

#### Sounds familiar...

This looks right so far. The `self._init_draw()` call draws my first frame immediately. Then the animation-object hooks into the figure-object and waits for the figure to be shown before attempting to draw any more frames for the animation.

#### Eureka!

The keyword is: animation-**object**. Since I wasn't planning on using the animation instance later (for example, to draw a movie), I didn't assign it to a variable. *In fact*, I was being **yelled at** by [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) because `Local variable '...' is assigned to but never used`.

But because all of the functionality relies on the hook, when the canvas is finally shown I presume Python's garbage collection has removed the Animation instance---since it was never assigned to a variable---and therefore the animation can never be started.

#### The fix

Simply assign the instance `FuncAnimation` instance to a variable, and everything works as expected!

```
anim = FuncAnimation(fig=fig,
                     func=update_lines,
                     frames=make_data,
                     fargs=(lines,),
                     interval=10,
                     blit=False)
```

Comment: Just assign `FuncAnimation` to `_` to prevent checker yelling.