# animating a surface with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying t animate a surface using matplotlib's built in animation routines, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  I'm loading some files from disk as follows:

```
def update_profile(j):
    File('u'+str(j)+'.xml')>>u
    u_tri = u.compute_vertex_values(mesh)
    ax.clear()
    plot = ax.plot_trisurf(mesh_tri, u_tri,cmap=cm.coolwarm,edgecolors='none')
    ax.set_title('$t$ = '+ str(dt * j))
    return plot,

fig =plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_profile, range(0,n_steps+1),
                              interval=10)
plt.show()
```

When individual files are loaded and plotted there's no problem.

Comment: You don't say what the problem is. Neither do you mention error messages if any.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  So it plots the initial frame, and then it does nothing; no error, but it never seems to update the image.

Answer (score 1):

I think I resolved this, but I'm not entirely sure why.  Looking at some of the examples, as soon as I changed

```
animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_profile, range(0,n_steps+1),
                              interval=10)
```

to

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_profile, range(0,n_steps+1),
                              interval=10)
```

it worked as expected.  Anyone understand why?

Comment: Yes - it's explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15328016/838992). It's kind of undocumented, but worth knowing. Might be worth replacing you last sentence in this answer with a link to that answer. Basically - the object needs to persist, so must be assigned to a variable or it will just... disappear!